# How to align a column in a text file

Tags: text-processing

Using bash on Linux, how can I process a text file such that space is inserted before a certain column so that column is aligned in the output? For example:

#### Input

```
1653455 ASDFASDF22 bla bla bla asd xmv ASDFASDF22 AA
1944444 ASDFASDF22 klasdfmxvl yxklc erisa ask xdk asdm ase ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl wqe ASDFASDF22 BB
```

#### Output

```
1653455 ASDFASDF22 bla bla bla asd xmv                                ASDFASDF22 AA
1944444 ASDFASDF22 klasdfmxvl yxklc erisa ask xdk asdm ase            ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl wqe ASDFASDF22 BB
```

The columns between the two `ASDFASDF22`s must be less than 50 characters, or it should be truncated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution using `perl`:

Content of **script.pl**:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Acept one argumnet, the input file.
@ARGV == 1 or die qq[Usage: perl $0 input-file\n];

while ( <> ) {
        ## Remove last '\n' char.
        chomp;

        ## Split line with string 'ASDFASDF22'
        my @f = split /(ASDFASDF22)/;

        ## Print line but print first 49 chars plus a space of the special string.
        printf qq[%s%-50s%s\n],
                join( qq[], @f[0,1] ),
                substr( $f[2], 0, 49 ) . qq[ ],
                join( qq[], @f[3..$#f] );
}
```

Execute the script:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

And output:

```
1653455 ASDFASDF22 bla bla bla asd xmv                              ASDFASDF22 AA
1944444 ASDFASDF22 klasdfmxvl yxklc erisa ask xdk asdm ase          ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl w ASDFASDF22 BB
```

Comment: omg. this answer is great!

Answer (score 2):

Using bash's arrays

```
while read -r -a words; do
    prefix="${words[0]} ${words[1]}"
    idx=${#words[*]}
    suffix="${words[$((idx-2))]} ${words[$((idx-1))]}"
    unset words[0] words[1] words[$((idx-2))] words[$((idx-1))]
    middle="${words[*]}"
    printf "%s %-50s %s\n" "$prefix" "${middle:0:50}" "$suffix"
done < filename
```

Comment: Nice.  `read -r` is generally recommended over plain `read`.

Comment: Thanks. I also neglected the `-a` option.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Birei's script on a text file I needed to columnize, but it failed because the file contained some lines that didn't match the given delimiter (and didn't need to be columnized). So with my poor knowledge of perl, I added a simple check of the size of the array to avoid processing non-matching lines. I'll post the basic code here in case someone else needs this change.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Acept one argumnet, the input file.
@ARGV == 1 or die qq[Usage: perl $0 input-file\n];

while ( <> ) {
    ## Remove last '\n' char.
    chomp;

    ## Split line with string 'ASDFASDF22'
    my @f = split /(ASDFASDF22)/;

    my $f = @f;
    # check array size to avoid errors on non-matching lines
    if ($f > 1)
    {
        ## Print line but print first 49 chars plus a space of the special string.
        printf qq[%s%-50s%s\n],
                join( qq[], @f[0,1] ),
                substr( $f[2], 0, 49 ) . qq[ ],
                join( qq[], @f[3..$#f] );

   }
   else
   {
       # output non-matching line as-is
       print $_ . qq[\n];
   }
}
```

So as an example of the output:

```
1653455 ASDFASDF22 bla bla bla asd xmv                              ASDFASDF22 AA
1944444 ASDFASDF22 klasdfmxvl yxklc erisa ask xdk asdm ase          ASDFASDF22 BB
######################### non-matching line left alone ##########################
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl w ASDFASDF22 BB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open("filename","r") 

a=[]

for line in f:

    if line[-1:]=='\n':
        line=line[:-1]

    a=line.split("ASDFASDF22")

    a.insert(1,"ASDFASDF22")

    a.insert(len(a)-1,"ASDFASDF22")

    k1=len(a[2])

    if k1 > 50:
        k2=k1-50
        k2=k2+1
        a[2]=a[2][:-k2]
        for i in a:
            print i,
    else:
        k2=50-k1
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
            if i !=2:
                print a[i],
            else:
                for j in range(0,k2):
                    a[2]=a[2]+" "
                print a[2],
    print ""`
```

This is a naive implementation in python. Save this as filename.py and give `python filename.py`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r one two line
do  printf "%s %s %-50.50s% %s\n" \   
       "$one" "$two" "${line%%"$two"*}" "$two${line#*"$two"}"         
done <<\DATA
1653455 ASDFASDF22 bla bla bla asd xmv ASDFASDF22 AA
1944444 ASDFASDF22 klasdfmxvl yxklc erisa ask xdk asdm ase ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl wqe ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl wqe hjbiub kuvyukvbklhb khuvbukvbuybouin ASDFASDF22 BB
DATA
```

You can do the above with most any POSIX shell.

#### OUTPUT

```
1653455 ASDFASDF22 bla bla bla asd xmv                                ASDFASDF22 AA
1944444 ASDFASDF22 klasdfmxvl yxklc erisa ask xdk asdm ase            ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl wqe ASDFASDF22 BB
1984945 ASDFASDF22 jklyck aklsdfl asfjasl asdkkcii wdkkkxd aslasl wqe ASDFASDF22 BB
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk:

```
awk -F "[[:space:]]+ASDFASDF22[[:space:]]+" \
    'BEGIN { OFS=" ASDFASDF22 "; }
    { 
        $2 = sprintf("%-50s", substr($2, 0, 50));
        print;
    }'
```